# Storing data as a property of a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how assigning data as a function variable on javascript works.

I've created fn() foo, and assigned a property foo.bar = {}, that I use to test cached requests. This works fine!

Meanwhile, I created an example using prototype, that I use to test and proof this concept ( http://jsbin.com/vowux/2/ ). Here, if we try it without the 'new' keyword, prototype won't work.

I'd like to know where I can find more information about storing data as a property of a function or get more information about why this works ?

```
function hasCache( param ) {

  var results;

  if ( hasCache.cache[param] ) {

    console.log('-> Cached:');
    results = hasCache.cache[param];

  } else {

    console.log('-> Not Cached:');
    results = param;
    hasCache.cache[param] = results;

  }

  return results;

}

hasCache.cache = {};

console.log( hasCache("foo") );
console.log( hasCache("foo") );
```

Live example available here http://jsbin.com/vowux/1/

Thanks for looking!

Comment: @BOSS: No it's not. Although you might want to [add `/edit` to the url](http://jsbin.com/vowux/2/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

instead of having the cache as a aprameter of your function that is available everywhere, even outside the function.

Using an IIFE gives you the ability to have a 'private' variable that holds your cache. For isntance:

```
var hasCache = (function() {

    var cache = {};

    return function(cacheKey) {
        if ( !cache.hasOwnProperty(cacheKey) ) {
            cache[cacheKey] = cacheKey;
        }
        return cache[cacheKey];
    }

})();
```

I also took the liberty refractoring your code. You had some strange things going on there.

Comment: Sorry. Your patter is fine, I've used it before. My question is actually understanding why assigning a property to a function works. Not sure if this is an anti pattern, but I'm trying to find more information about this.

Comment: functions in JS are objects ;)